Repead reads from JPA repository return the same value
I have this code snippet from a Spring Java web app (with spring data and postgresql DB) and  I don't understand the results I get from it. Let's say I have an entity that comes down to (some details omitted for brevity)
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

and a coresponding repo:
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {}

and a service with 3 calls:
public class MyService {

    private CountDownLatch changeName = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private CountDownLatch firstRead = new CountDownLatch(1);

    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public void readNameTwice() throws InterruptedException {
        String oldName = myRepository.getById(ENTITY_ID).getName();

        firstRead.countDown();
        changeName.await();

        String newName = myRepository.getById(ENTITY_ID).getName();
        System.out.println("newName same as oldName? " + newName.equals(oldName));
    }

    public void changeName() throws InterruptedException {
        firstRead.await();

        MyEntity myEntity = myRepository.getById(ENTITY_ID);
        myEntity.setName("new name");
        myRepository.save(myEntity);

        changeName.countDown();
    }

    public void getSecondName() throws InterruptedException {
        firstRead.await();
        changeName.await();
        MyEntity myEntity = myRepository.getById(ENTITY_ID);
        System.out.println("getName() = " + myEntity.getName());
    }
}

I have a controller that simply calls those methods:
    @GetMapping("/readNameTwice") public void readNameTwice() throws InterruptedException { myService.readNameTwice(); }
    @GetMapping("/changeName") public void changeName() throws InterruptedException { myService.changeName(); }
    @GetMapping("/getSecondName") public void getSecondName() throws InterruptedException { myService.getSecondName(); }


and I call all 3 endpoints at the same time. I've introduced latches to make sure the order of the execution is:
first readNameTwice reads a name for the first time, then changeName changes it, and then readNameTwice continues with a second read, and also getSecondName reads a name.
What I don't understand is how readNameTwice both times reads the same (old) name? getSecondName gets the new name, as expected, but I'd expect to have different names being read in readNameTwice method, since I didn't use the @Transactional annotation. Is there an implicit transaction here? If so, can someone point me to some blog post or something to read more about it?
PS. The result is the same even if I add some more wait time in readNameTwice method (after changeName.await() call). But if I implement MyRepository as a in-memory DB (simple map of type Map<Long, MyEntity>) then readNameTwice reads different names, as I would expect.

Make sure you have: spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

Thanks, that's the "implicitness" of transaction I was trying to figure out. Now I know where to look further.
